# Populate cache before app is fully available

Tags: uwsgi

Is there a uWSGI option/hook/subsystem to fill a cache before an app is ready to process requests?
The static `load-file-in-cache` is not an option. I need to call a function or program which populates a uWSGI cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prerequisite is that uWSGI actually has caching enabled, something like:

```
[uwsgi]
cache2 = name=mycache,items=100
```

There are many options for startup hooks. Take a look at [this page in the uWSGI doc](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Hooks.html). You can choose at what point in the uWSGI startup sequence you want to hook up (`as-root`, `as-user`, `pre-app`, `accepting1`, ...) and you have the choice between shell exec (`exec`) and function calls (`call`).

The config directive may look something like:

```
[uwsgi]
call-as-root = cache_clear("mycache")
call-as-user = cache_set("key", "value")
```

See also [Cache functions](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Caching.html#accessing-the-cache-from-your-applications-using-the-cache-api).

I believe that `load-file-in-cache` directive may also be able to handle your problem:

```
[uwsgi]
exec-as-user=/usr/local/bin/populate_my_cache_folder.sh
for-glob = /my/cache/folder/*.*
    load-file-in-cache = files %(_)
endfor =
```

Comment: I have already seen these hooks but I'm not clear how to fill a cache of a starting uWSGI instance from within a called script ... ?

Comment: Ah thanks, I was not aware that one can use these cache functions form within a uWSGI config ... but one last thing :) how to do this for variable number of key value pairs - e.g. some database records?

Comment: @hooblei Please take a look at my new edit. I found a way to harness the power and flexibility of a shell script. Basically you prepare a directory with the files you want to cache (copy from a different place, generate from some script or binary, ...) and then iterate over the files using a glob pattern.

Comment: A bit heavy to write everything on disk before reading it into memory but at least it will do it :) - thanks.